# How do I configure a startup/config script for Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I am looking to define a set of custom aliases/variables for use every time I launch PowerShell. I am looking for the PowerShell alternative to the `.bashrc` file.

I have tried putting a file named `Profile.ps1` in the home directory, but it never runs. What do I need to do to get this file to run?

I am using Windows 10.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd start by reading through Microsoft's documentation [about_Profiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-5.1). I've linked to the 5.1 version of the documentation since that's likely what you have on Windows 10, though I doubt it has changed much from version to version. It includes instructions on how to actually create the file and details about when it runs.

For your use case, you probably want to do the following from your session:

```
if (!(Test-Path -Path $PROFILE)) {
  New-Item -ItemType File -Path $PROFILE -Force
}
```

which will generate the profile. Then once that is generated you can open it with notepad directly with the same example from there:

```
notepad $PROFILE
```

You can substitute your favorite editor for notepad. [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) for instance would be:

```
code $PROFILE
```

You can also just get the path to the your profile by simply typing `$PROFILE` into the shell and it will output it, and then use that information to navigate to it from your favorite editor.

Per the documentation:

> A PowerShell profile is a script that runs when PowerShell starts.

It's more complicated than that since there are multiple profile files as the documentation explains, but for your story it's accurate enough.

You can always also ['dotsource'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-5.1#dot-sourcing-operator-) your profile to make it run manually by executing:

```
. $Profile
```

However you should note that objects previously defined by prior invocations of your profile might not be removed. So while developing your profile that's a useful technique, be sure to only trust how it behaves when run by opening a completely new session.

Answer (score 4):

> I have tried putting a file named `Profile.ps1` in the home
>   directory, but it never runs.

`Profile.ps1` will work, though not in the `$Home` directory, but rather in the `$Home\[My ]Documents\[Windows]PowerShell\Profile.ps1`. The actual combination between `[My ]Documents` and `[Windows]PowerShell` depends on the versions of Windows and PowerShell, as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-5.1).

On my Windows 10 with PS 5.1 the right place for `profile.ps1` is `$home\Documents\WindowsPowerShell`.

The candidate locations for profile files can also be checked via PowerShell itself.

```
PS C:\etc> $profile | get-member -name *user*

   TypeName: System.String

Name                   MemberType   Definition
----                   ----------   ----------
AllUsersAllHosts       NoteProperty string AllUsersAllHosts=C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\profile.ps1
AllUsersCurrentHost    NoteProperty string AllUsersCurrentHost=C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
CurrentUserAllHosts    NoteProperty string CurrentUserAllHosts=C:\Users\XXXXXXXX\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1
CurrentUserCurrentHost NoteProperty string CurrentUserCurrentHost=C:\Users\XXXXXXXX\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
```