# Is there a way to automatically run an initialization script when starting Windows 10 Powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, anaconda

I have a couple of Windows 10 Powershell commands that I always enter at the start of a terminal session (to do key bindings to enable using up arrow to auto-complete a command from my command history).  I made a shell script to do this, but is there a way to make it run automatically when I start the Powershell?

More details that may be relevant:

- I am actually using the Anaconda Powershell (which I understand to be just a Windows Powershell).
- The two commands are: `Set-PSReadlineKeyHandler -Key UpArrow -Function HistorySearchBackward Set-PSReadlineKeyHandler -Key DownArrow -Function HistorySearchForward`
- I currently have them in a script called init.ps1 that I can run when I start the Powershell (obviously, by typing init.ps1 ).

##############################

EDIT:  Thank you for the response.  Someone pointed out that there was a similar question posted:
[How do I configure a startup/config script for Powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61492112/how-do-i-configure-a-startup-config-script-for-powershell)

Between these answers, I was able to set up a configuration script by creating a directory, `C:\Users\(user)\Documents\WindowsPowerShell` and placing a script called `Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you would like to create a profile, and Microsoft's documentation has information on which type of profile, and other information at the following webpage,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-7.1&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-7.

Comment: Thank you.  Someone pointed out that there was a similar question posted:
How do I configure a startup/config script for Powershell?